# My transaction's max time is going beyond a minute

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, performance, java, query-performance

I have a transaction called "updatePolicyStatus" whose response time is usually under a 3 seconds for many instances during a peak load. This transaction processes bunch of business rules and fires big set of SQLs to database. But  during a peak load, 10% of the total transactions response time is going beyond a 60 seconds. When I look at individual queries they are fine. I am not quiet sure what else is causing the transaction to become slow once in a while? My database I/O, network, CPU and memory everything is fine tuned. Could you please let me know what else could be the bottleneck? My database is Oracle 11g and it has 100 Gigs of data.

Comment: What do you mean by "When I look at individual queries they are fine"?  What, specifically, are you looking at?  Are you looking at the AWR/ ASH information for the executions of those statements during the period when the transaction time exceeds a minute?  Or are you looking at the statements in isolation later?  I'm not sure what you mean when you say that I/O, CPU, memory, and network are "fine tuned".  Are you saying that some tool tells you that when things have plenty of additional capacity when performance is poor?  What does AWR/ ASH tell you are the wait events?

Comment: When I say "When I look at individual queries they are fine" means that, when my transaction is executed for 100 times during an hour of load test, I get response time below 3 seconds for 90 times and only for the remaining 10 times the response time for the same transaction goes beyond 60 seconds.When I say my resources (I/O, CPU, memory...etc) are fine tuned means that, they are not heavily overloaded by requests (I monitor it manually, CPU is always below 15% (8 CORE CPU), memory is below 50% (24 Gigs of RAM....etc). I am not using AWR/ASH, I use appDynamics and as well as visualVM.

Comment: Are you saying that you cannot use AWR/ASH data (possibly because of license issues)?  Or that you don't want to?  Or that you can but you're not sure how?  I'd certainly want to zoom in on the data Oracle collects about individual executions to see if you're occasionally getting different query plans or whether there is some wait event that is happening periodically like row lock contention.

Comment: I cannot setup AWR/ASH on my database, because it may effect my database's overall performance, isn't it. My DBA has enabled performance stats for this DB and collects metrics after every test. When you say AWR/ASH, do you mean Oracle Enterprise manager? I suspect the issue can be waits which may be occuring, because many of my queries are making full table scans during the execution. Is there any easy way to find out the these kind of waits (user i/o waits, lock contention...etc) other than AWR?

Comment: If you're licensed for it, the overhead of AWR statistics gathering is generally pretty minimal.  If you've disabled AWR snapshots and ASH because of performance concerns, you're throwing away a lot of data that would help debug this issue.  Enterprise Manager does have screens that display data from the AWR and ASH tables but you can also query the data directly.  The easy way to see wait events, unfortunately, is to look at the AWR data.  You could also trace the session (that will make the session much slower and can have a noticable impact on database performance).

Comment: If you can monitor the system while you reproduce the error, you could also use the data from the dynamic performance views.  That's harder to arrange (DBAs tend not to be particularly happy to have people in running ad-hoc queries against dynamic performance views at peak load when there are performance problems).  And it requires that you be pretty efficient at it.  AWR snaps all that data off so you can analyze it at your leisure potentially on a different system rather than trying to do your analysis while the issue is happening.

Comment: I have checked with my DBA, the AWR seems to be not available for us. Did you know about "Who is Active v11.11"? Any idea on how to run it against my database?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11469/discussion-between-user1614862-and-justin-cave)

Comment: There is a Who Is Active 11.11 that works on SQL Server 2005 and 2008.  It seems unlikely that you would be able to run it against an Oracle database. http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2012/03/22/released-who-is-active-v11-11.aspx

Comment: If you're not licensed for the diagnostic pack, you can still use Statspack to help